# Change password program in java using netbeans

Tags: java, database, swing

After all the fuss I used JAVA DB and now using apache Derby client driver to use and after finally entering my database i have a new problem

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String uname = jTextField1.getText();
    String strpass = jPasswordField1.getText();
    String newpass = jPasswordField2.getText();
    String conpass = jPasswordField3.getText();

    try
    {
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver());
    }
    catch(SQLException ex1)
    {
        ex1.printStackTrace();
    }

      try      
    {

        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/niiitusers");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from app.userlogin");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String usrname = rs.getString("username");
            String passwd = rs.getString("password");
            if(uname.equals(usrname) && strpass.equals(passwd))
            {

                if(newpass.equals(conpass))
                {
                    Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet i = st1.executeQuery("UPDATE app.userlogin SET password='newpass' where username='usname'");//query i am using to update the password
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PASSWORD UPDATE SUCCESSFUL");

                }

                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PLEASE CONFIRM PASSWORD");
                }}
            else if(uname.equals("") && strpass.equals("") && newpass.equals(""))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PLEASE ENTER ALL INFORMATION");
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "USERNAME NOT FOUND");
            }
            st.close();

            con.close();
        }

    }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



}                                        

java.sql.SQLException: executeQuery method can not be used for update.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
```

Its not performing the update operation. I am not sure where the problem is

Answer (score 1):

it's not showing any output because your catch block has nothing in it.

First off, this needs to change...

```
catch (SQLException ex) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} }
```

Secondly, I'd look at the obvious stuff, are you using the right credentials?  Is the IP address correct for the db?

Either way, the stacktrace will give you the answers you need.

Comment: its throwing an error tat says suitable driver not found. But i have used the same driver for another program. It works

Comment: Is the jar in your build path?  It sounds like it's missing.

Comment: Building jar: C:\Users\RockN Roll\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PasswordChange\dist\PasswordChange.jar

Comment: My other program is working perfectly fine with the database.Seems really weird to me

Comment: @user2186265 then you clearly have something not working in this program ;)

Comment: To start off i would create a separate class just for making connection between your program and database, instead of throwing it all into the same class

Answer (score 1):

dont use executeQuery for updating password.
rather, use executeUpdate for updating. 
and it has no Resultset 
use it like this

```
    if(newpass.equals(conpass))
            {
                Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
                st1.executeUpdate("UPDATE app.userlogin SET password='newpass' where  
    username='usname'");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PASSWORD UPDATE SUCCESSFUL");

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove rs and use `executeUpdate()` instead of `executeQuery()`

the last `else` statement is also unnecessary